# How to Calculate Http Request Header Size in a CloudFlare Worker?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

We are running services of various technologies (ex: SpringBoot, node.js, golang etc.) behind Amazon API Gateway. Due to marketing requirements some requests are added additional cookies. In a recent demo we found that in some scenarios we got ERROR 431/400 due to the exceed of maximum header value size of the request (For ex: [SpringBoot has a default maximum allowed Http Request Header size limit of 8K](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/spring-boot-app-rejects-http-request-with-total-header-size-larger-than-8kb?language=en_US)). Since Request Header size is limited to 10K [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) in the Gateway, we are planning to add a Cloudflare worker to block requests with Request Header Size more than 10K. At the same time increase the underlying services' allowed header size to 10K.

My question is how can I calculate the HTTP Request header's size inside Cloudfare worker?
Currently I'm using TypeScript and I'm totally new to it. [Here](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-workers-announces-broad-language-support/#:%7E:text=Today%2C%20we%27re%20excited%20to,your%20favorite%20language%20starting%20today.) is the list of languages supported in Cloudflare.
And any suggestions of alternative solutions would be really appreciated.